# I can't submitt form in laravel modal window

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

when I click the button, the modal window opens with the input date field and the two buttons close and save the data-id is assigned correctly. The problem is that I can not send data from the form that is in the modal window. As I write down, nothing happens.

Below the form field:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-idp="{{$car->id}}" data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Wycofaj</button>


<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">

     <!-- Modal Header -->
       <div class="modal-header bg-danger text-light">
         <h4 class="modal-title">Wycofanie pojazdu</h4>
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       </div>
       ID:<input type="text" name="idp" id="idp" value="{{$car->id}}" />
        <!-- Modal body -->
         <div class="modal-body">
          <form  method="POST" action="{{ URL:to('pojazdy.wycofaj')}}" >
           @csrf
           @method('PATCH')
           Wprowadź datę wycofania pojazdu: 
           <input type="date" id="data_wyc" name="data_wyc" />
           <input type="hidden" id="idp" name="idp" value="{{$car->id}}" />
         </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Wycofaj</button>
       <input type="hidden" name="idp" id="idp" value="{{$car->id}}" />
       </form>
    </div>

     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

jquery code :

```
    $('#myModal').on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {

       $("#idp").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('idp'));

       $("#data_wyc").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('data_wyc'));
     });
```

I test

```
route('pojazdy.wycofaj' ,'idp')
```

and

```
URL::to('/pojazdy/wycofaj')
```

my controller - WykazPojController

```
    public function wycofaj(Request $request)
      {
        $cars = \App\WykazPoj::findOrFail($request->idp);
      }
```

and my route

```
   Route::get('pojazdy/wycofaj/{id}', 'WykazPojController@wycofaj');
```

Result who i want: send data from form with input date to WykazPojController and function wycofaj() who update field in db change status on '2' number and date from input date ( from modal window ).

Comment: There is no PATCH route. This will throw a 404.

Comment: I use {{ route('pojazdy.wycofaj' ,'idp') }} but not work route::resoruce only for crud how this change ?

Comment: there is no named route 'pojazdy.wycofaj' in your code.

Comment: this not correct named route ? Route::get('pojazdy/wycofaj/{id}', 'WykazPojController@wycofaj'); im new in laravel

Comment: That is an unnamed route. It has an **URI** (`pojazdy/wyzofaj/{id}`), an **action** (`WykazPojController@wycofaj`) but no **name**. To give it a name, declare it like this: `Route::get('pojazdy/wycofaj/{id}', 'WykazPojController@wycofaj')->name('pojazdy.wycofaj');` However, that is a **GET** route and your form tries to send a **PATCH** request. If you want a PATCH route, just use `Route::patch(....)` instead of `Route::get(.....)`

Comment: i change my route: Route::patch('pojazdy/wycofaj/{id}', 'WykazPojController@wycofaj')->name('wycofaj'); and <form  method="POST" action="{{ route('wycofaj','idp')}}" > and nothing happens only after click button in window modal that close.

Comment: here is all app code : https://github.com/page4me/transport in this link is modal window https://github.com/page4me/transport/blob/full-master/resources/views/przedsiebiorca/cars.blade.php

Comment: Does it throw an error at all? Try `{{ route('wycofaj', ['id' => $car->id]) }}` and `\App\WykazPoj::findOrFail($this->route('id'))`

Comment: no error is displayed even if I changed according to your record, nothing happens either just like I click the save button it closes the modal window as if it did not work all submitt

Comment: What if you remove the `data-dismiss="modal"` from your submit button?

Comment: when i remove data-dismiss="modal" i have error http://localhost:8000/przedsiebiorca/cars/%7B%20route('wycofaj',%20['id'%20=%3E%20$car-%3Eid])%20%7D%7D  and The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Comment: I repaire error i miss one { in {{ route('wycofaj', ['id' => $car->id]) }} when change this i have a http://localhost:8000/pojazdy/wycofaj/25 and message : Method App\Http\Controllers\WykazPojController::route does not exist. This id not from record with button. This id is last form db

Comment: The PATCH method is not supported for this route is what I told you earlier about `Route::get` and `Route::patch`. The other error is my mistake. Instead of `$this->route('id')` try `$request->route('id')`.

Comment: i use {{ route('wycofaj', ['id' => $car->id] ) }} and in WykazPojController $cars = \App\WykazPoj::findOrFail($request->id); because $request->route('id') not work. Now send id from form action but this id is last row in db. This not correct id who i want. as if the form did not send data from input fields only what is in the action = "{{route ...}}" path. I need to send the id of a given record and the date I enter in the input date field. How to check if he sent data from input fields? how do I print_r ($ request-> id) show id from the action path